# Kendo DatePicker Red border if validation fails

Tags: kendo-ui

Can i add Red Border to `Kendo UI date picker` if validation fails

```
function onChange(e) {
    if (e.date == undefined) {
        var item = $(this).find('.t-input').val('Incorrect date!');
    }
}
```

I have this `onChange` Method and trying to add `red` border. Can anyone help me or suggest a better solution

Answer (score 2):

Adding this CSS should work:

```
#datepicker[aria-invalid] {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

Here is an example:
[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ufimom/360/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this with Kendo UI.
Kendo UI elements do not allow you to do this.

I did data binding with the style sheets on a kendo widget.
Firebug will inform you that it is not possible.

I will open a ticket with my telerik support account now and come back to you.
I would also like to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```html
$('input[aria-owns=txt-orderedTime_timeview]').closest(".k-picker-wrap.k-state-default").css("border-color", '#ff0000');
```

> OR

```html
$("#txt-orderedTime").data("kendoTimePicker").wrapper.find(".k-picker-wrap.k-state-default").addClass("validationErrorClass");
```

```html
.validationErrorClass {
        border-color: #ff0000 !important;
    }
```